# Unable to retrieve and id from posted data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am trying to add comments on a joke thread, but I am having trouble grabbing the joke_id which should be used to amend the comments on the post.

The problem i face is, the thread with no comments on will not add the joke_id to the database, and the thread with comments on works fine. I have no idea why.

This is a working example of what I am talking about:

http://ehustudent.co.uk/cis21732825/cis3122/jokehut_4/read/joke/14

This thread is fully working (i just emphasised the joke_id for test purposes)

and this thread does not work:

http://ehustudent.co.uk/cis21732825/cis3122/jokehut_4/read/joke/4

The comment and name is added to the database, but the joke_id is down as '0' and i have no idea why.

Here is my code in the view:

```
    <?php

    //assigning values
    foreach($results as $row){
        $name = $row->name;
        $joke = $row->joke;
        $joke_id = $row->joke_id;
        $date_added = $row->date_added;
        $vote = $row->vote;

    ?>


    }

        echo form_open('comments/insertComment');

        ?>

        <div class="new-com-bt">
            <span>Write a comment ...</span>
        </div>

        <div class="new-com-cnt">
            <input type="text" id="name-com" name="name-com" value="" placeholder="Name is optional" />
            <textarea  required="yes" class="the-new-com" id="the-new-com" name="the-new-com" placeholder="Write your comment here..."></textarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="joke_id" value="<?= $joke_id; ?>">

            <input class="bt-add-com" type="submit" value="Post comment">
            <div class="bt-cancel-com">Cancel</div>
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>


    <?php

    echo form_close(); ?>
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function index(){

    $this->getComment();

}

public function getComment(){

    $data['results'] = $this->comments_m->getComments();

    $this->load->view('template/header');
    $this->load->view('template/sidebar');
    $this->load->view('content/comment_box', $data);
    $this->load->view('template/footer');

}

public function insertComment(){

    $data = array (
        'user' => 'user',
        'comment' => 'comment',
        'joke_id' => 'joke_id',
        'id_post' => 'joke_id'
    );

    $joke_id = $this->input->post('joke_id');

    $this->comments_m->insertComment($data);
    redirect(base_url('read/joke/'.$joke_id));

}
```

}

model:

```
 //gets the comments
    function getComments ($joke_id){
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT c.name, j.*, co.* FROM jokes j LEFT JOIN category c ON c.category_id = j.category_id LEFT JOIN comments co ON co.joke_id = j.joke_id WHERE j.joke_id =  '$joke_id' ") or die("No results found" );

        if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        }
    }

    //inserts the comments
    function insertComment (){

        $data = array (
            'user' => $this->input->post('name-com'),
            'comment' => $this->input->post('the-new-com'),
            'joke_id' => $this->input->post('joke_id'),
            'id_post' => $this->input->post('joke_id')
        );

        if(strlen($data['user']) < 1){
            $data['user'] = "Guest";
        }

        $this->db->insert('comments', $data);


    }
```

comments table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `comment` text NOT NULL,
  `joke_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_post` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

jokes table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jokes` (
  `joke_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `joke` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vote` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`joke_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Any help as to why the joke_id doesn't insert/show on pages with no jokes would be great.

Thank you

Comment: "joke_id doesn't insert/show on pages with no jokes" - if there isn't a joke then there can't be a joke_id.

Comment: Comments can only be made when their is a joke.

Comment: In your view, you have : `<input type="hidden" name="joke_id" value="<?= $joke_id; ?>">` but shouldn't it be: `<input type="hidden" name="joke_id" value="<? echo $joke_id; ?>">` ???

Comment: <?= is just a short hand way of saying <? echo

Comment: @CrescentMoon using <?, which is short open tag, is bad practice but using <?= is not, since php 5.4 this is enabled by default and is not disabled even though short open tag is